# SwiftUI - Return image from function to view

Tags: function, swiftui, google-places-api

I have a function that is grabbing an image of a business from Google Places after I pass in the Places ID. I'm able to 'print' the photo and see the actual photo from the function I've written, I'm just not sure how to return that image so that I can place it within the view. My thought is that I could return the image from the function and have it replace the 'placeHolderImage' in the view.

Here's the code:

```
struct RestaurantDetail: View {


var name: String
var placeID: String
var address: String
var city: String
var state: String
var zipCode: String
var phone: String
var about: String
var website: String
var inputLat: Double
var inputLong: Double
var foodType: String
var fileURL: String

@State var placeHolderImage = Image(systemName: "flag.fill")


var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack {

        placeHolderImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(height: 150)
            .clipped()
                .padding(.bottom)



            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("About")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                HStack {
                    Text(about)
                        .font(.footnote)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)

                HStack {
                    Text("Location")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.horizontal)
               MapLocation(inputLat: inputLat, inputLong: inputLong, inputTitle: name, inputFoodType: foodType)
                    .frame(height: 160)


                HStack {
                    Text(name)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }.padding(.vertical, 10)
                HStack {
                    Text(address) + Text(", ") + Text(city) + Text(", ") + Text(state) + Text(" ") + Text(zipCode)

                }.font(.system(size: 13))
            }
        }
    }.onAppear {
        self.getPhotos(placesID: self.placeID)
    }
}

func getPhotos(placesID: String) -> (UIImage)  {
    let client = GMSPlacesClient()
    print("getPhotos function ran")
    client.lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (metadatalist, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("error when looking up photos:", err)
            return
        }
    //    print(metadatalist)
        guard let firstPhotoMetadata = metadatalist?.results.first else { return }

        client.loadPlacePhoto(firstPhotoMetadata) { (image, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to load photo for place:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let placeImage = image else { return }
            print(placeImage)

            return placeImage

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, if API set up correct it should work

```
func getPhotos(placesID: String)  {  // async, so no return needed
    let client = GMSPlacesClient()
    print("getPhotos function ran")
    client.lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (metadatalist, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("error when looking up photos:", err)
            return
        }
    //    print(metadatalist)
        guard let firstPhotoMetadata = metadatalist?.results.first else { return }

        client.loadPlacePhoto(firstPhotoMetadata) { (image, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to load photo for place:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let placeImage = image else { return }
            print(placeImage)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {   // state must be updated in main queue
                 self.placeHolderImage = Image(uiImage: placeImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```